# YouTube won't let my PC sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-options

I see that there are many people looking for a way to prevent sleeping when they are watching a video, [like this one](https://superuser.com/questions/99391/prevent-display-from-turning-off-due-to-inactivity-when-watching-full-screen-vid). I am sorta opposite. With the help of

```
powercfg -requests
```

I have determined that my system is blocked from sleeping by the "VIA HD Audio" device. That is, my PC darkens the screen but keeps the system running when this device is used.

After I have updated its driver, I noticed that `powercfg` complemented the audio device with chrome.exe, which now blocks the screen whenever YouTube is playing.

So now the PC does not even switch the screen to pretend that it is sleeping.

Should I disable the audio/video devices or there is a better option that respects sleep timeout in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, internet knows about this issue. We need to disable `Allow Applications to Prevent Automatic Sleep` in the Local Policies Editor. If your are happy users of other than Home Windows editions, you can even try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
POWERCFG /REQUESTSOVERRIDE PROCESS "\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" SYSTEM AWAYMODE EXECUTION
```

At least the display should be put in sleep mode correctly. For the box you need to edit the power saving settings to match the video length.